# OR statement in sqlite3: error?

Tags: sql, sqlite, boolean-expression

my sql query in sqlite3 ends with a OR statement. It looks like this:

```
select
   (...)
from
    T1, T2, .... Tn

where
     (...) and
     (
     (T5.v='s1' and T6.v='s2' and T7.v='s3') OR
     (T5.v='s4' and T6.v='s5' and T7.v='s6')
     )
```

the query returns **no** result.

However each distinct 'OR' conditions returns some rows (!)

```
where
     (...) and
     (
     (T5.v='s1' and T6.v='s2' and T7.v='s3')
     )
```

and

```
where
     (...) and
     (
     (T5.v='s4' and T6.v='s5' and T7.v='s6')
     )
```

is it a bug in sqlite3 or is it me ?

```
$ sqlite3 -version
3.6.20
```

update: I've got  three non-unique indexes on T5.v, T6.v and T7.v

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but the changelog of sqlite 3-6-22 includes fixes for "bugs that can (rarely) lead to incorrect query results when the CAST or OR operators are used in the WHERE clause of a query"

Comment: And another bug involving OR was fixed in 3-7-4 - see http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/80ba201079

Comment: @DidierSpezia I've updated the sources of sqlite and it works fine now! Thank you for the suggestion !

Comment: @DidierSpecia can you post your comment as an answer so that Pierre can accept it. This is showing as unanswered. Thanks

Comment: @DidierSpezia Seconded comment from Edmundo - please help keep StackOverflow tidy by posting the answer and accept so others don't think this is unanswered.

Comment: Well, I was just lucky on this one - but I understand your point. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said previously in the comments, the [changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html) of sqlite **3-6-22** includes:

```
Fix bugs that can (rarely) lead to incorrect query results when the CAST or OR operators are used in the WHERE clause of a query.
```

Another OR bug was fixed in **3-7-4**:

http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/80ba201079

Another one in **3-7-14-1**:

```
Fix a bug (ticket [d02e1406a58ea02d]]) that causes a segfault on a LEFT JOIN that includes an OR in the ON clause.
```

and another one in **3-7-17**:

http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/f2369304e4

I would suggest to upgrade to a more recent sqlite version, and see if it fixes the issue.